# Dynamic array guarantee clarification

Tags: arrays, dynamic

In Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual, he mentions at one point:

```
The primary thing lost using dynamic arrays is the guarantee that each array
access takes constant time in the worst case. Now all the queries will be fast, except
for those relatively few queries triggering array doubling. What we get instead is a
promise that the nth array access will be completed quickly enough that the total
effort expended so far will still be O(n).
```

I'm struggling to understand this. How will an array query expand the array?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic arrays are arrays where the size does not need to be specified (Think of an ArrayList in java). Under the hood, dynamic arrays are implemented using a regular array. Though, because it's a regular array the implementation of the ArrayList needs to specify the size of the underlying array.

So the typical way to handle this in dynamic arrays is to initialize the standard array with a certain amount of elements, then when it reached it's maximum elements, the array is doubled in size.

Because of this underlying functionality, most of the time it will take constant time when adding to a dynamic array, but occasionally it will double the size of the 'under the hood' standard array which will take longer than the normal add time.

If your confusion lies with his use of the word 'query', I believe he means to say 'adding or removing from the array' because a simple 'get' query shouldn't be related to the underlying standard array size.